# The Castle clearing for Preston in Taking Independence

Tags: fallout-4

The quest "Taking Independence" is not going smoothly, as I cleared out all of the Mirelurk eggs and Mirelurks, even all the way down to the small dock and surrounding areas.  Every time I try to speak to the guy standing in the rubble near the transmitter, only keeps saying there are more enemies to kill and they could be in the walls.  I checked everything on top and in the open area of the armory and nothing is left to kill.  I then try to go use the workstation and it tells me "cannot use while enemies in area".  I am stumped and stuck.

Comment: Have you tried speaking to Preston? There are indeed enemys left (don't want to spoiler the surprise ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

I believe your fallout 4 savefile is glitched, because by that time the Mirelurk Queen should have spawned and you were meant to battle it. I have played this part of the game recently, so unless you have missed something it is glitched.